# How to remove parallel stripes from DEM in QGIS or GRASS?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, dem, hillshade, shaded-relief

I have DEM (*.tif) from which I need to create shaded relief in GRASS/QGIS.
Problem is that it appears to have some parallel stripes all across the raster, as on picture below.

I used resampling method (Warp(Reproject)) to visually increase resolution, and I filtered the raster with GRASS function *r.neighbors*.

Then I created shaded relief using *r.relief* and the stripes become more visible.

How can I remove those stripes?

original DEM
[image]

shaded relief
[image]

Comment: There is a QGIS processing tool `Destriping` in `SAGA | Raster Tools`. Unfortunately I have no experience with this tool, but an article by SAGA module author [SRTM DEM destriping with SAGA GIS](http://www.webalice.it/alper78/saga_mod/destriping/destriping.html) may guide you.